# jquery .css return constant name for font-weight

Tags: jquery, css, properties

I've set the font-weight of an element like so

```
$('#myid').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

When I later try and verify the value of it

```
$('#myid').css('font-weight')
```

it returns the actual font-weight as an integer.

Additionally when no font-weight has been set on a new element the value returns 400 (which is the default).

Should I change the way I am expecting to get these values back and always expect them to be a number and have to do some comparison to tell if the value is the default value or the element is infact "bolder" or is there another way that will actually return the pseudo names assuming the font-weight matches one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$('#myid').prop('style').fontWeight` since `.css()` applies css via the style property of the DOM nodes this will retrieve the `fontWeight` property of the style attribute

Comment: is that cross browser?

Comment: I believe so. However it will only ever return values you have explicitly set by using `.css()` or applying a style to an element. It wont find styles that were applied through a stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) will return the computed value of the styles as it is assigned to the element, so in this case you can expect it to be a number